# Linux: How to set location that command to run

Tags: command-line, clang

Clang-3.9 and clang-5.0 are installed in my computer,
but clang-3.9 seems to be set default. (Because clang-3.9 runs when I type "clang".)
Now, I want to switch them temporary.

How to set location that command to run?

I'm Japanese, so some statements might be wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to find out where the executable file you want is. As a step toward that, find out where the one that is actually running is like this:

```
whereis clang
```

Then I'd open the indicated directory with a graphical file browser and look for the one you want. Or, of course, you can do the same thing with commands like `cd ..` and `ls` and so on. It is probably up and over one so to speak. For example, if the command you do NOT want is in /usr/bin/clang-3.9/ then the one you DO want is probably is a directory like /usr/bin/clang-5.0/ or something similar.

Then invoke it with the full path, like:

```
/usr/bin/clang-5.0/clang
```

or whatever. I just used that particular path as an example of the principle. You'll have to find the correct path.

I hope I understood the question correctly.